# How to use a for loop or Laaply to truncated t random variable on stock data to simulate option prices using foptions library

Tags: r, lapply

I generate a list of truncated random t variables, then download closing stock price (quantmod) then generate a list of possible random stock prices, when I try and plug this into a loop in lapply  or for each, the random variates are not recognized.
Below is my code the lapply function gives an error:

```r
library(truncdist)
library(quantmod)
library(fOptions)

randomT <- rt(4,6)
randomOut <- dtrunc(randomT, spec = "t", df = 6,a= -2, b= 2)
startDate <- as.Date("2018-01-01") 
# Specify period of time we are interested in
randomOut <- randomT
endDate <- as.Date("2019-05-09") 
getSymbols('SPY',src='yahoo',from = startDate,to = endDate)
SpRtn <- dailyReturn(SPY,type='arithmetic')

rtn <- sum(SPYreturns)
dev <- sd(SPYreturns)
vol <- dev*sqrt(250)
dt <- 1/250
current <- tail(SPY$SPY.Close,1)
dayRtn <- rtn*dt
dayVol <- vol*sqrt(dt)
guess <- function (randomOut) current * exp(dayRtn + Vol * randomOut)
expected <- lapply (randomOut, FUN = guess)

gsb <- function() {
    GBSOption (TypeFlag = "p", S = expected,
               X = 280,
               ime = 18/250,
               r = 0.022,
               b = 0,
               sigma =0.16
               )
}

lapply(expected, FUN = gsb)
```

Comment: You've dumped a lot of poorly formatted code here and asked us to fix it. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Some of it doesn't make a lot of sense: `randomOut` is assigned and then immediately overwritten, comments span multiple lines without `#`, and `Vol` is used in the `guess` function but never assigned (although there is a `vol`). Also, you say **the** lapply function, but there are two, and you don't tell us which one is causing problems. Please clean up your code and whittle things down to something more manageable.

Comment: The last lappy does not generate an answer, the first lapply operates well. The vol function in guess should be dayVol, and Time is misspelt in gsb function.

Comment: I admit my code is poor but I am new to coding in R, you have deleted some crucial parts needed to run I am adding back and editing and posting

Comment: error > lapply(expected, FUN = gsb)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])
>

Comment: fixed code below, still with above error.

Comment: randomT <- rt(4,6) must be run first line then randout<-randomT line must be deleted

Comment: I have trouble  with the stack overflow editing and how to add code , it confuses me no end, the instructions might make sense to a human code robot, they are definitely not user friendly to the average user.

Comment: the comments were left over from a cut and paste,and  were not needed I forgot to delete in haste.

Comment: Instead of just listing the problems with the code you should fix them.

Comment: I've formatted your code without changing it. Please take a look at how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in the code you provide. It's great that you're so ambitious, but I would recommend that you slow down a bit and focus on cleaning up things up, and on understanding how the parts work and how they interact.

I've added comments where there were specfic issues. Please read them and try to understand each issue. Please also understand that I had to make some guesses about your intentions, as I don't really know anything about this topic. Still, I was able to get things working just by fixing some variable names and making sure the objects being passed into functions had the correct class. In particular, `GBSOption` requires a numeric variable for `S`, but `expected` has class `xts`. You need to subset it with something like `S = expected[[1]]` to get it working.

This code should run, but I can't guarantee that it's doing what it's supposed to do:

```r
library(truncdist)
library(quantmod)
library(fOptions)

# You assign randomOut using dtrunc, then immediately overwrite it with 
# randomT. Is that a mistake?
randomT <- rt(4,6)
randomOut <- dtrunc(randomT, spec = "t", df = 6, a = -2, b = 2)
#randomOut <- randomT

# Specify period of time we are interested in
startDate <- as.Date("2018-01-01") 
endDate <- as.Date("2019-05-09") 

getSymbols('SPY', src = 'yahoo', from = startDate, to = endDate)
SpRtn <- dailyReturn(SPY, type = 'arithmetic')

# You use SPYreturns in your orginal code, but there is no assignment to 
# SPYreturns. Do you mean SpRtn?
rtn <- sum(SpRtn)
dev <- sd(SpRtn)
vol <- dev * sqrt(250)
dt <- 1/250
current <- tail(SPY$SPY.Close, 1)
dayRtn <- rtn*dt
dayVol <- vol*sqrt(dt)

# You use `Vol` in the `guess` function, but the variable is called `vol`.
guess <- function (randomOut) current * exp(dayRtn + vol * randomOut)
expected <- lapply (randomOut, FUN = guess)

gsb <- function(expected) {
    GBSOption (TypeFlag = "p",
               # This was probably your biggest issue. `expected` points to an
               # xts object, but you need numeric, which means you need to
               # extract the first SPY.Close value.
               S = expected[[1]],
               X = 280,
               # You had `ime` here, but you need `Time`.
               Time = 18/250,
               r = 0.022,
               b = 0,
               sigma =0.16
               )
}

lapply(expected, FUN = gsb)
```

Comment: Yes I appreciate your hardwork that is exactly what i set out to achieve, you picked out the errors I found and semantic and syntax errors I could not understand, It was done with some haste. what it is showing is that conventional finance theory states that stock returns are log normal, this was using trumps trade crises crash to test that prices actually can be simulated during these times with a truncated t -distribution with 6 degrees of freedom, I was estimating the possible effect on a particular spy option strike. Thank you very much, how do I leave you  positive feedback?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works @nhoj. You can leave positive feedback by accepting using the ✓ to the left, and also by upvoting the answer.